# Atmel at91saml21j18b board configuration error with Jtag connectivity Through Openocd Server

Tags: atmel, atmelstudio, openocd, jtag

Hello actually i'm trying to interface a samdl21 board with Jtag through openocd server.I'm facing some problem in configuration where it is throwing Invalid ACK (0) in DAP response Error...someone please help me to find a solution for this problem.

--------check the below  logs for error--------

```
    Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-00738-gc3b90c0 (2019-03-12-12:23)
    Licensed under GNU GPL v2
    For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
    WARNING!
    This file was not tested with real interface, but is assumed to work as this
    interface uses the same layout as configs that were verified. Please report your
    experience with this file to openocd-devel mailing list, so it could be marked
    as working or fixed.
    Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "jtag". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
    adapter speed: 1500 kHz
    none separate
    adapter speed: 400 kHz
    cortex_m reset_config sysresetreq
    Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
    Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
    Info : clock speed 400 kHz
    Error: JTAG scan chain interrogation failed: all zeroes
    Error: Check JTAG interface, timings, target power, etc.
    Error: Trying to use configured scan chain anyway...
    Error: at91samd.cpu: IR capture error; saw 0x00 not 0x01
    Warn : Bypassing JTAG setup events due to errors
    Error: Invalid ACK (0) in DAP response
    Error: Invalid ACK (0) in DAP response
```

------------Configuration Script used for interface-----------------

```
# script for Atmel SAMD, SAMR, SAML or SAMC, a Cortex-M0 chip
# samdXX devices only support SWD transports.

source [find target/swj-dp.tcl]

if { [info exists CHIPNAME] } {
   set _CHIPNAME $CHIPNAME
} else {
   set _CHIPNAME at91samd
}

if { [info exists ENDIAN] } {
   set _ENDIAN $ENDIAN
} else {
   set _ENDIAN little
}

# Work-area is a space in RAM used for flash programming
# By default use 2kB
if { [info exists WORKAREASIZE] } {
   set _WORKAREASIZE $WORKAREASIZE
} else {
   set _WORKAREASIZE 0x800
}

if { [info exists CPUTAPID] } {
   set _CPUTAPID $CPUTAPID
} else {
   set _CPUTAPID 0x4ba00477
}
adapter_khz 1500
#swj_newdap $_CHIPNAME cpu -irlen 4 -expected-id $_CPUTAPID
jtag newtap $_CHIPNAME cpu -irlen 4 -ircapture 0x1 -irmask 0xf -expected-id $_CPUTAPID -ignore-version

dap create $_CHIPNAME.dap -chain-position $_CHIPNAME.cpu

set _TARGETNAME $_CHIPNAME.cpu
target create $_TARGETNAME cortex_m -endian $_ENDIAN -dap $_CHIPNAME.dap

$_TARGETNAME configure -work-area-phys 0x20000000 -work-area-size $_WORKAREASIZE -work-area-backup 0

# dsu_reset_deassert configures whether we want to run or halt out of reset,
# then instruct the DSU to let us out of reset.
$_TARGETNAME configure -event reset-deassert-post {
        at91samd dsu_reset_deassert
}

# SRST (wired to RESET_N) resets debug circuitry
# srst_pulls_trst is not configured here to avoid an error raised in reset halt
reset_config srst_gates_jtag

adapter_khz 400

# Atmel's EDBG (on-board cmsis-dap adapter of Xplained kits) works
# without problem at maximal clock speed. Atmel recommends
# adapter speed less than 10 * CPU clock.
# adapter_khz 5000

if {![using_hla]} {
   # if srst is not fitted use SYSRESETREQ to
   # perform a soft reset
   cortex_m reset_config sysresetreq
}

set _FLASHNAME $_CHIPNAME.flash
flash bank $_FLASHNAME at91samd 0x00000000 0 1 1 $_TARGETNAME
```